# I need help improving my SQL query for pulling a recent document count

Tags: sql, query-optimization, azure-sql-database

This is just a portion of the query, but it seems to be the bottleneck:

```
SELECT CAST (CASE WHEN EXISTS
             (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.CBDocument
              WHERE (FirmId = R.FirmId) AND
                    (ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())) AND
                    ((EntityTypeId = 2600 AND EntityId = P.IProductId) OR
                    (EntityTypeId = 2500 AND EntityId = M.IManagerId)))
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS HasRecentDocuments

FROM  dbo.CBIProduct P
  JOIN dbo.CBIManager M ON P.IManagerId = M.IManagerId
  JOIN dbo.CBIProductRating R ON P.IProductId = R.IProductId
  JOIN dbo.CBIProductFirmDetail D ON (D.IProductId = P.IProductId) AND
                                         (R.FirmId = D.FirmId)

CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 RatingDate, IProductRatingId, FirmId
             FROM  dbo.CBIProductRating
     WHERE (IProductId = P.IProductId) AND (FirmId = R.FirmId)
     ORDER BY RatingDate DESC) AS RD

WHERE (R.IProductRatingId = RD.IProductRatingId) AND (R.FirmId = RD.FirmId)
```

There are a lot of other columns that I typically pull back that need the CROSS APPLY and the other joins. The bit I need to optimize is the sub-query in the case statement. This subquery takes over 3 minutes to return 119k records. I know enough about SQL to get this far, but there has to be a way to make this more efficient.

The gist of the query is just to return a flag if the associated product has any documents that have been added to the system within the last 3 months.

Edit: My DB is hosted in Azure and the database tuning advisor won't connect to it. There is a tuning advisor component in Azure, but it's not suggesting anything. There must be a better approach to the query.

Edit: In an attempt to further simplify and determine the culprit, I whittled it down to this query: (Rather than determine if a recent doc exists, it just counts recent docs.)

```
SELECT D.FirmId, P.IProductId,
       ,(SELECT COUNT(DocumentId) FROM dbo.CBDocument WHERE
        (FirmId = D.FirmId) AND
        (ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())) AND
        ((EntityTypeId = 2600 AND EntityId = P.IProductId) OR
        (EntityTypeId = 2500 AND EntityId = M.IManagerId))) AS RecentDocCount

FROM dbo.CBIProduct P
FULL JOIN dbo.CBIProductFirmDetail D ON D.IProductId = P.IProductId
JOIN dbo.CBIManager M ON M.IManagerId = P.IManagerId
```

That runs in 3 minutes, 53 seconds.

If I declare a variable to store the date (`DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE()`)
 and put the variable in place of GETDATE() in the query (`DATEADD(m, -3, @Today)`), it runs in 12 seconds.

Is there a known performance issue with GETDATE()? As far as I know, I can't use the variable in a view definition.

Does this shine any light on anything that could point to a solution? I suppose I could turn the whole thing into a stored procedure, but then I also have to adjust the application code.

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/dta/tutorial-database-engine-tuning-advisor Do this and you might get lucky and only have to add some new indexes

Comment: Thanks, @Will. I've been down that path. I can't connect the DTA to my DB in Azure and Azure's tuning advisor isn't recommending anything.

Comment: If you can snag the db, and load it into a local instance of sql server, you could still try. Indexes wouldn't be different in azure, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on stuff it may be faster to use a left join:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE when x.FirmId is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS HasRecentDocuments

FROM  dbo.CBIProduct P
  JOIN dbo.CBIManager M ON P.IManagerId = M.IManagerId
  JOIN dbo.CBIProductRating R ON P.IProductId = R.IProductId
  JOIN dbo.CBIProductFirmDetail D ON (D.IProductId = P.IProductId) AND (R.FirmId = D.FirmId)


LEFT JOIN dbo.CBDocument x ON x.FirmId = R.FirmId 
                          AND x.ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())
                          AND (   (x.EntityTypeId = 2600 AND x.EntityId = P.IProductId) 
                               OR (x.EntityTypeId = 2500 AND x.EntityId = M.IManagerId))

CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 RatingDate, IProductRatingId, FirmId
             FROM  dbo.CBIProductRating
     WHERE (IProductId = P.IProductId) AND (FirmId = R.FirmId)
     ORDER BY RatingDate DESC) AS RD

WHERE (R.IProductRatingId = RD.IProductRatingId) AND (R.FirmId = RD.FirmId)
```

it certainly looks simpler.

Comment: Had to adjust the syntax a bit to stop SQL Server from complaining, but this doesn't seem to yield the same results...  It does run a bit faster, but I'll have to figure out why I'm getting a different result set. Also, the CASE seems to have issues with the NULL check. I only get 0's.

Comment: hmmm, what was the change (saw I was missing a `when` something else?) -- I don't think the case has issues with the null check -- what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is the query that you claim needs optimization:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM dbo.CBDocument d
                              WHERE (d.FirmId = R.FirmId) AND
                                    (d.ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())) AND
                                    ((d.EntityTypeId = 2600 AND d.EntityId = P.IProductId) OR
                                     (d.EntityTypeId = 2500 AND d.EntityId = M.IManagerId)
                                    )
                            )
    . . .
```

I'll trust your judgement.  I think phrasing the query like this gives you more paths to optimization:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM dbo.CBDocument d
                              WHERE d.FirmId = R.FirmId AND
                                    d.ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE()) AND
                                    d.EntityTypeId = 2600 AND d.EntityId = P.IProductId 
                            ) OR
                      EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM dbo.CBDocument d
                              WHERE d.FirmId = R.FirmId AND
                                    d.ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE()) AND
                                    d.EntityTypeId = 2500 AND d.EntityId = M.IManagerId
                            ) 
    . . .
```

Then you want an index on `CBDocument(FirmId, EntityTypeId, EntityId, ContributionDate)`.

Answer (score 1):

Operations such as `correlated subqueries` and `full outer join` are rather expensive and I would suggest looking for alternatives to those. Whilst I am not familiar with your data model or data, I suggest the changing the "from table" to `CBIProductFirmDetail` and I have further assumed an inner join the product table and the manager table then inner joined to the product table. If that join sequence is correct this removes the expense of some outer joins.

In place of the correlated subquery to determine a count, I suggest you treat that as a subquery which is left joined.

```
SELECT
      d.FirmId
    , p.IProductId
    , COALESCE(Docs.RecentDocCount,0) RecentDocCount
FROM dbo.CBIProductFirmDetail d
JOIN dbo.CBIProduct p ON d.IProductId = p.IProductId
JOIN dbo.CBIManager m ON p.IManagerId = m.IManagerId
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            FirmId
          , EntityId
          , EntityTypeId
          , COUNT(DocumentId) recentdoccount
      FROM dbo.CBDocument
      WHERE ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())
      AND EntityTypeId IN (2500,2600)
      GROUP BY
            FirmId
          , EntityId
          , EntityTypeId
) AS docs ON d.FirmId = docs.FirmId
         AND (
              (docs.EntityTypeId = 2600 AND docs.EntityId = p.IProductId)
           OR (docs.EntityTypeId = 2500 AND docs.EntityId = m.IManagerId)
             )
;
```

There might be benefit in dividing that subquery too to avoid the awkward OR in that join, so:

```
SELECT
      d.FirmId
    , p.IProductId
    , COALESCE(d2500.DocCount,0) + COALESCE(d2600.DocCount,0) RecentDocCount
FROM dbo.CBIProductFirmDetail d
JOIN dbo.CBIProduct p ON d.IProductId = p.IProductId
JOIN dbo.CBIManager m ON p.IManagerId = m.IManagerId
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            FirmId
          , EntityId
          , COUNT(DocumentId) doccount
      FROM dbo.CBDocument
      WHERE ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())
      AND EntityTypeId = 2500
      GROUP BY
            FirmId
          , EntityId
) AS d2500 ON d.FirmId = d2500.FirmId
         AND m.IManagerId = d2500.EntityId
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            FirmId
          , EntityId
          , COUNT(DocumentId) doccount
      FROM dbo.CBDocument
      WHERE ContributionDate > DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())
      AND EntityTypeId = 2600
      GROUP BY
            FirmId
          , EntityId
) AS d2600 ON d.FirmId = d2600.FirmId
           AND p.IProductId = d2600.EntityId
;
```